# why to use jqgrid(client side) rather using asp.net grid view(server side)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, webforms, jqgrid-asp.net

i know how to use jqgrid and asp.net grid(server side) also.but i have basic question. why should one use  jqgrid(client side) if they have gridview control (server side).please Add why to use client side development if every thing is ready on server side development.
please Answer,
thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer below site for better knowledge

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

It will help u !!!!

Comment: By doing processing on client side you are reducing load on server. Also while choosing the client or server side processing make sure what are your requirements i.e. security, behavior, and server trips for dependent data etc

Comment: @GirishSakhare now a days secure app also using clientside dev ...give me strong reason.to answer server side dev. i have refferd above link...

Comment: @Pankaj, basically my comment's first part says if you can perform something on client side then why not? and the other part suggests some considerations. Server side as you know will consume server resource and trips. Once you have all the data that you need at client end then its economical and fast to process/render the way one want there itself.